# nested structs that contains pointer members

Tags: c++, struct

I have a question on linked list, and they defined a Node struct:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}
```

that i can't change, so i created new struct in oreder to succeed answering the question:

```
struct tmpNode{
    int data;
    bool visit = false;
    struct Node* next;
} t;
```

now i'm trying to do the folowing code but it failed on the last line - the purpose is to create parallel list with the struct i created:

```
t.data = head->data;
t.visit = true;
t.next = head->next;
t = t.next;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: C++ does not require you do write `struct Node*`, `Node*` is sufficient

Comment: @Curious - You'd need to forward declare it for that too work. Otherwise you need the fully decorated identifier.

Comment: @StoryTeller https://wandbox.org/permlink/zT5BYZ6cv880fT5y I have never had to do `struct Node*` before..

Comment: @Curious - Interesting. Learn something new every day. I need to re-read the standard on symbol introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign incompatible types. Type of `t.next` is `Node*`, while type of `t` is `tmpNode`.

Comment: and there isn't a type cast that i can do so it will work?

Comment: I assume you have to keep track of which nodes have been visited without modifying the original `Node` struct. A solution I recommend is to store this information externally in a container, for example in a `std::map<Node *, bool>`.

Comment: great i didn't thought about something like this.. thanks!

Comment: Even simpler: use a set with only the nodes that have been visited.

Comment: @DanielJour, I agree. Set is more appropriate.